# Pandas : When the 'apply' function is applied to the column, the 'NaN' value is output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

In today's year, if the difference in the year of the corresponding column is 5 or more, it is designed to output 1, but the NaN value comes out.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()

def time(x):
  if today.year - x.year > 5:
    x = 1
    return x
  else:
    x = 0
    return x

df['VIP'] = df[condition]['DaysSinceJoined'].apply(time)
df['VIP']
```

Get an error:

```
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
        ..
2235   NaN
2236   NaN
2237   NaN
2238   NaN
2239   NaN
Name: VIP, Length: 2240, dtype: float64
```

Comment: If you have a column with timestamp of them joining, you could use a custom function to calculate. I think DaysSinceJoined column you have is integer format.

Comment: What is `condition`? Is `DaysSinceJoined` a datetime column? Time function can be reduced to `return today.year - x.year > 5`, could further be reduced to a lambda function within apply.

Comment: condition = (df['TotalMntProducts'] > 2000)

Comment: I have ran into similar issues. Then it was that my formatting was off. Make sure your column is datetime. I suggest you try to do this without apply first: df.loc[(df['DaysSinceJoined'].dt.year - 2017) > 5, 'over_5 Y'] ='yes' If this fails, you know it's not apply but underlying data issue. Edit: You might want to paste a few rows of your data so we can test.

Answer (score 0):

The function works just fine. The issue might lie within your initial condition:

Fist lets generate a bit sample data:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'time':['1979-11-10','1962-07-22','1987-09-16','2020-09-16']})

from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today()

def time(x):
   if today.year - x.year > 5:
      return 1
   else:
      return 0
```

First we make sure it's not data format issue as I suggested above:

```
foo['VIP'] =foo['time'].apply(time)
```

> 'str' object has no attribute 'year'

We fix this by converting the dates to datetime:

```
foo['time'] = pd.to_datetime(foo['time'])
```

Lets test the function:

```
foo['VIP'] =foo['time'].apply(time)
```

> time   VIP
> 0   1979-11-10  1
> 1   1962-07-22  1
> 2   1987-09-16  1
> 3   2020-09-16  0

All good.

Now lets apply some random condition:

```
foo['VIP'] =foo[foo['time'].dt.year >1980]['time'].apply(time)
```

> time   VIP
> 0   1979-11-10  NaN
> 1   1962-07-22  NaN
> 2   1987-09-16  1.0
> 3   2020-09-16  0.0

Reason is that you first filter your dataframe to smaller bit and then feed those rows to your function. Because they are never processed they don't get return values.

I suggest you do this with *.loc* function:

```
foo.loc[(( today.year - foo['time'].dt.year > 5 ) & (Other_condition_here), 'vip'] = 1
foo.loc[(( today.year - foo['time'].dt.year <= 5 ) & (Other_condition_here), 'vip'] = 0
```

For more about .loc see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you use .apply it takes several arguments. Use map:

```
df['VIP'] = df[condition]['DaysSinceJoined'].map(time)
```

or:

```
df['VIP'] = df[condition].apply(lambda x: time(x['DaysSinceJoined']))
```

If it didn't work, show us some sample data.